# Rails 4 Server sent events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, push-notification

How in Rails 4 using Server Sent Events and listen multiple callbakcs (create and destroy)? For example,

Model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :notify_job_created
  after_destroy :notify_job_destroyed

  def self.on_create
    Job.connection.execute "LISTEN create_jobs"
    loop do
      Job.connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, job|
        yield job
      end
    end
  ensure
    Job.connection.execute "UNLISTEN create_jobs"
  end

  def self.on_destroy
    Job.connection.execute "LISTEN destroy_jobs"
    loop do
      Job.connection.raw_connection.wait_for_notify do |event, pid, job|
        yield job
      end
    end
  ensure
    Job.connection.execute "UNLISTEN destroy_jobs"
  end

  def notify_job_created
    Job.connection.execute "NOTIFY create_jobs, '#{self.id}'"
  end

  def notify_job_destroyed
    Job.connection.execute "NOTIFY destroy_jobs, '#{self.id}'"
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class StreamJobsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live

  def index_stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

    sse = SSE.new response.stream
    begin
      Job.on_create do |id|
        job = Job.find(id)
        stand = Stand.find(job.stand_id)
        t = render_to_string(
          partial: 'projects/stand',
          formats: [:html],
          locals: {stand: stand}
        )
        sse.write(t, event: 'create')
      end
      Job.on_destroy do |id|
        job = Job.find(id)
        sse.write(job.stand_id, event: 'destroy')
      end
    rescue IOError
      # When the client disconnects, we'll get an IOError on write
    ensure
      sse.close
    end
  end
end
```

JS code:

```
$(function () {
  var source = new EventSource('/jobs_stream');

  source.addEventListener('create', function(e){
    console.log('Create stand:', e.data);
    $("table.project-stands.table.table-condensed").find("tbody#stand-list").prepend($.parseHTML(e.data));
  });

  source.addEventListener('destroy', function(e){
    console.log('Destroy stand: ', e.data);
    var id = e.data;
    $("table.project-stands.table.table-condensed").find("tr#stand_" + id).remove();
  });

 source.addEventListener('finished', function(e){
   console.log('Close:', e.data);
   source.close();
 });
});
```

As result, I get only LISTEN create_jobs. What's wrong in my controller? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything is wrong with your controller. Your question is more about Postgres notifications than anything else. Do you have tests for the methods you are using in your ActiveRecord models that ensure the NOTIFY/LISTEN combinations function as they should?

> As result, I get only LISTEN create_jobs

What do you mean by that? I don't see any LISTEN stuff coming into the SSE output in the example you have posted. I would really suggest you experiment with the model on it's own to see if the blocking waits you are using etc. function in isolation, and then try putting SSE on top as a transport.